# Question regarding the use of the AM-GM inequality in optimisation problems.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

So I am solving a problem which involves finding the maximum value of $a$, given that $a + bc + bd + cd + \frac{1}{ab^{2}c^{2}d^{2}}=18$ and $a, b, c, d \in\mathbb{R^+}$.

What I tried doing was applying the AM-GM inequality as follows:$$\frac{\frac{a}{2} + \frac{a}{2} +bc + bd + cd + \frac{1}{ab^{2}c^{2}d^{2}}}{6} =\frac{18}{6}=3\ge\sqrt[6]{\frac{a}{2}\cdot\frac{a}{2}\cdot bc\cdot bd\cdot cd\cdot \frac{1}{ab^{2}c^{2}d^{2}}}=\sqrt[6]{\frac{a}{4}}$$

This yields $4\cdot 3^6\ge a$, which is different from the official solution $16\ge a$, which is obtained like this:$$a +bc + bd + cd + \frac{1}{ab^{2}c^{2}d^{2}}=\frac{a}{32}+\ldots+\frac{a}{32} + bc + cd+ bd + \frac{1}{ab^{2}c^{2}d^{2}}\\\ge36\cdot\sqrt[36]{\frac{a^{32}}{32^{32}}\cdot bc\cdot cd\cdot bd\cdot \frac{1}{ab^{2}c^{2}d^{2}}}=36\cdot\sqrt[36]{\frac{a^{31}}{32^{32}}}$$

And thus: $18\ge36\cdot\sqrt[36]{\frac{a^{31}}{32^{32}}}\implies a^{31}\le\frac{32^{32}}{2^{36}}=2^{124}\implies a\le{2^4}=16.$

Can you please help me see my error? How can I ensure that I apply the AM-GM inequality correctly in future problems?

Comment: Remember to check equality cases. Note that if equality cannot hold, then it is absurd to take the result immediately.

Comment: Echoing Lim, all that you've done is found an upper bound. To show that it is a maximum (least upper bound), you will need to do more. One thing that you can do is demonstrate that equality can hold. For example, while it is true that $ x^2 \geq - 1$, the minimum of $x^2$ is not $-1$.

Comment: So the right thing to do would have been to try splitting $a$ into $\frac{a}{2} + \frac{a}{2}$, take the inequality and check for a contradiction and then try again successively by splitting $a$ into increasing powers of $2$ until I found some power of two $2^k$ for which taking the equality wouldn't lead to a contradiction?

Comment: @MushroomTea there is no "universal" method to figure out the right use of AM-GM. In this particular case, what you are saying would work but not in general.